# htaccess mod_rewrite carry folder names over

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect a URL with whatever folder is on the end to a new URL and I can't get the rewritecond figured out.

I'm trying to take URL like this:

http://www.example1.com/feature/this-folder-name/whatever1/whatever2

to

http://www.example2.com/whatever1/whatever2

The folder whatever1 can change as can whatever2.

I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example1\.com/feature/this-folder-name$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example2.com/$?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

And

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example1\.com/feature/this-folder-name$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `℅{HTTP_HOST}` variable only contains the host header ie `example.com` not url path see the Apache mod-rewrite  manual https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues here, so I took the liberty to clean things up a bit...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example1\.com/$
RewriteRule ^/?feature/this-folder-name/(.*)$ https://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301,END,QSA]
```

In case you want to be more precise and *really* only redirect if two separate folders are specified as you explained this might point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example1\.com/$
RewriteRule ^/?feature/this-folder-name/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? https://www.example2.com/$1/$2/ [R=301,END,QSA]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

These rules will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you for the direction.  I ended up using your first suggesting and tweaking it a bit.  Got rid of the RewriteCond and just did ^feature/this-folder-name/(.*)$

Comment: That is fine as long as both hosts are defined separate, so do not share that rule. This always is a risk when using those dynamic configuration files: you risk rewriting loops. But all is fine if things are really separate.

Comment: About the pattern itself... I learned to use the `^/?` prefix to keep rules valid and independent such that they can be used in dynamic configuration files _or_ in the real host configuration. That makes my solutions much more portable. But may have other priorities.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example1.com
redirect / http://example2.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost*:80>
ServerName example2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Then let example2.com do what it does in its own virtual host settings. The assumption here is example2 knows where it’s own files are, independent of example1.